# Bigquery -INSERT INTO

Tags: google-bigquery, insert, numeric

I am getting the following ERROR when attempting this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO xxxx.Dxxxx.tbl_cluster_data
    WITH source1 as (
         SELECT string_field_0,string_field_1, double_field_2, double_field_3,double_field_4
         FROM xxxx.xxxx.tbl_temptable 
         WHERE NOT string_field_0 IN ('ABCD','FQ')
           )
     SELECT *
     FROM source1
```

Error:

> Query column 3 has type FLOAT64 which cannot be inserted into column XXXXX, which has type NUMERIC

Schema:

```
Field name      Type    MODE
double_field_2  FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

I have tried creating the table (tbl_cluster_data) I want the data inserted into with different data types to no avail.

When I load the data into my temptable from cloud storage, column #3 comes in as FLOAT64

I am using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE  xxxx.xxxx.temptable
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris =['xxxx']
);
```

What data type can I import FLOAT64 into?
Is there a way to control the data type of the imported data from a csv file into the temptable?

I have tried changing the data type of the column I want the data imported into to different data types like NUMERIC, BIGNUMERIC.

I tired to change my final table column type to FLOAT, that is not possible in a create statement apparently.

I want to create a final table with the column names and data types I need,  I want to use the temptable to insert the data into the final table.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I can think of is altering the schema of your tables to match the data types of both tables.

You can see reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_data_type) from BQ documentation.